# How do I find the required parameters for the payload when logging into a website with requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

This is what I have so far.  I'm very new to this so point out if I'm doing anything wrong.

```py
import requests

url = "https://9anime.to/user/watchlist"

payload = {
    "username":"blahblahblah",
    "password":"secretstringy"
    # anything else?
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    res = s.post(url, data=payload)

print(res.status_code)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to inspect the form and see where the form is posting to in the `action` tag. In this case it is posting to `user/ajax/login`. Instead of requesting the watchlist URL you should post those details to the `loginurl`. Once you are logged in you can request your watchlist.

```py
from lxml.html import fromstring
import requests

url = "https://9anime.to/user/watchlist"
loginurl = "https://9anime.to/user/ajax/login"

payload = {
    "username":"someemail@gmail.com",
    "password":"somepass"
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    res = s.post(loginurl, data=payload)
    print(res.content)
    # b'{"success":true,"message":"Login successful"}'
    res = s.get(url)
    tree = fromstring(res.content)
    elem = tree.cssselect("div.watchlist div.widget-body")[0]
    print(elem.text_content())
    #   Your watch list is empty.
```

Comment: Where did the `div.watchlist div.widget-body` come from?  btw, your'e awesome this worked!  But, I actually prefer using Beatifulsoup over lxml and I'm not really familiar with how lxml works either.

Comment: No need to stick to lxml if you don’t like it. It’s probably easier with BS4, but I just wanted to show you an example. That watch list div was the one I saw on the watch list page containing the important data, which was empty since I just created an account to test. Use BS4 with find/findAll and you’ll be good.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to have knowledge (documentation of some form) on what that URL is expecting and how you are expected to interact with it.  There is no way to know just given the information you have provided.

If you have some system that is able to interact with that URL already (e.g. your able to log in with your browser), then you could try to reverse-engineer what it is your browser is doing...